# python script in microsoft ser

Tags: python, sql-server

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to wrap my head around microsoft server 2017 and python script.
In general - I'm trying to store a table I took from a website (using bs4),
storing it in a panda df , and then simply put the results in a temp sql table.

I entered the following code (I'm skipping parts of the code because the python script
does work in python. Keep in mind I'm calling the script from microsoft sql server 2017):

```
    CREATE PROC OTC 
AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'

import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests
....
r = requests.get(url, verify = False)
html = r.text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
data_date = str(soup.find(id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_4be2cf24_5a47_472d_a6ab_4248c8eb10eb_ctl00_lDate").contents)
t_tab1 = soup.find(id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_4be2cf24_5a47_472d_a6ab_4248c8eb10eb_ctl00_NiaROGrid1_DataGrid1")
df = parse_html_table(1,t_tab1)
print(df)
OutputDataSet=df
'
```

I tried the microsoft tutorials and simply couldn't understand how to
handle the inputs/outputs to get the result as a sql table.

Furthermore, I get the error

"
  import bs4 as bs
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
"

I'm obviously missing a lot here.
What am I to add to the sql code? 
does the sql server even supports bs4? or only pandas? 
and then I need to find another solution like write as csv?

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer

Comment: missing module you could try installing by using pip  - like  pip install bs4

Comment: Just entering the code "pip install beautifulsoup4" / "pip install bs4" into the script doesn't work. Running the script from the server, I'm not even sure where and how the server installs the packages (and if it even supports them)

Comment: but you need to have the required packages installed to make it work

Comment: I'm totally down with that, but how do I install bs4 on the microsoft 2017 server management studio? couldn't find the answer on google. I even wonder if it CAN be installed

Comment: How do you run the code on your server? Can you run other programs from there? If so, run `pip install beautifulsoup4` and then try your code again.

Comment: I Run it from the server management studio 2017. the install doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use pip to install a Python package on SQL Server 2017:

- On the server, open a command prompt as administrator.
- Then `cd` to `{instance directory}\PYTHON_SERVICES\Scripts`
  (for example: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\Scripts`).
- Then execute `pip install {package name}`.

One you have the necessary package(s) installed and the script executes successfully, simply setting variable `OutputDataSet` to a pandas data frame will result in the contents of that data frame being returned as a result set from the stored procedure.

If you want to capture that result set in a table (perhaps a temporary table), you can use `INSERT...EXEC` (e.g. `INSERT MyTable(Col1, Col2) EXEC sp_execute_external_script ...`).